# Duplicate Int in Array , Dictionary or Set in SWIFT

Tags: arrays, swift

Reading up on Sets and Arrays I find that a Set cannot, or is not able to store duplicate values ( Ints, Strings, etc ).

Knowing this, if we are to solve for finding a duplicate Int in an array and one method is to convert the Array to a Set, how come we don't get an error once the Array is a Set?

The methods below simply return a Bool value if the array contains duplicates.

```
import UIKit

func containsDuplicatesDictionary(a: [Int]) -> Bool {

    var aDict = [Int : Int]()

    for value in a {
        if let count = aDict[value] {
            aDict[value] = count + 1
            return true
        } else {
            aDict[value] = 1
        }
    }

    return false
}

containsDuplicatesDictionary(a: [1,2,2,4,5])

func containsDuplicatesSet(a: [Int]) -> Bool {
    return Set(a).count != a.count
}

containsDuplicatesSet(a: [1,2,2,4])
```

The first function, containsDuplicatesDictionary, I convert the array to a Dictionary, of course this takes a for loop as well. The Set method can be done in one line, which is really nice. But I guess since I am new to this, I would think converting the array would throw an error immediately since theres duplicate values.

What am I missing when it's converted

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Set, by design is an unordered, unique collection of elements. The implementation of Set takes care of duplicate values itself, when you try to add a duplicate value, it checks whether the value is already present in the Set or not and if it is, the value is not added.

When you call the initializer of Set that takes a sequence as its input parameter (this is what you use when writing `Set(a)`, where `a` is of type `[Int]`, under the hood, the initializer adds the elements one by one checking whether any of the new elements are already present in the Set or not.

You could make a custom initializer method for Set that would throw an error if you would try to add a duplicate value to it, but it wouldn't really have any advantages for any users of Swift, hence the current implementation that just doesn't add the value if it is already present in the Set and doesn't throw an error. This way, you can safely and easily get rid of any duplicates in a non-unique collection of elements (such as an array).

Comment: Okay, so if I wanted to append another Int of the same value, I can just convert it back into an array.